# Envoyer Deployment Hook Failing to install composer

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, digital-ocean, envoyer.io

I am new to envoyer. I tried to deploy my first laravel 5 project using envoyer and I keep getting an error in the `Install Composer Dependencies` part of the deployment hook.

`Using global Composer installation.
bash: line 17: composer: command not found`

I don't know what I am doing wrong. 
I have successfully added my server, ssh keys and ssl certificate.

I am using `laravel forge` and `DigitalOcean`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though you have one of two problems:

1. Composer is not installed on the server
2. Envoyer is using the incorrect path to composer

Depending on the type of server, you might be able to run `which composer` on the server to determine the path to composer. If no path comes back, that would indicate that composer is not installed. Then, within envoyer, specify the path to composer via the "update server" button next to the server, where you can specify the composer path.